# How to have a Linux VM join the domain and get a hostname

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, fedora, virtualbox

I'm using Virtualbox on my desktop, WinXP host, and guest running Fedora 12.
I want to set it up as a LAMP testing server mostly for me, but it should be visible to the whole company LAN.

- I set up the VM in Virtualbox to use 'Bridged adapter' network, attached to the host network connection.
- I can ping the guest's IP from the host.
- But I can't ping it's hostname.

What do I need to set up in order to be able to access the VM by hostname locally within the LAN? e.g. vmdev1.company.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS needs to be setup, either manually (via editing a zone file or some GUI thing), or automatically (DHCP server registers the name associated with the IP address it leased with the DNS server).

Comment: I need to do this in the guest or the host? Any guidelines or link with more info? I appreciate the help thanks

Comment: You do it on your DNS/DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to join the VM to your domain, try Likewise Open:

http://www.likewise.com/products/likewise_open/

This should also automatically add an entry for your host into DNS.